# How to loop through paginated cursor REST API with Python

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

Hi so I have a REST API where all paginated endpoints use cursor based pagination.

The response will be something like:

```
GET /endpoint?limit=100
{
  "results": [...],
  "next": "c29tZWJhc2U2NA=="
}
```

I want to write the "results" to a dataframe, use the "next" cursor to pull the next page, and then write the subsequent page's results to the same dataframe.

According to documentation, I will find a "null" or "None" value for "next" when I reach the last page:

```
GET /endpoint?limit=100&from=c29tZWJhc2U2NA==
{
  "results": [...],
  "next": null
}
```

I have written the following code, but I have not been able to get to the next cursor ("next") value:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

endpoint = url
api_key = "Basic redacted"
params = { 'Authorization': api_key}

#instantiate dataframe
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
#set cursor to empty string to make initial GET request
cursor = ""

#while loop to evaluate cursor until it becomes None when it reaches the last page
while cursor is not None:
    #set parameters to make GET request
    dynamic_params = { 'Authorization': api_key, 'next': '{0}'.format(cursor)}
    #make GET request
    response = requests.get(endpoint, headers=dynamic_params)
    #convert GET response to JSON
    json_response = response.json()
    
    #pull next cursor and set cursor to store next cursor
    cursor = json_response['next']
    print(cursor)   
    
    #convert json response to a dictionary
    vitally_dict = json.dumps(json_response)
    
    #convert dictionary to str
    dict_to_str = json.loads(vitally_dict)
    
    #write str to dataframe
    df = pd.json_normalize(dict_to_str['results'])     
    
    #append dataframe to final dataframe
    final_df = final_df.append(df)
```

For starters, the while loop runs seemingly infinitely. The default settings pull 100 results per page and I know there are just over 6,500 results, which means I shouldn't have to pull more than 67 pages (and that there should be 67 unique "next" cursors). When I open final_df after the while loop, the cursor does not refresh and simply writes the same 100 results to final_df.

Comment: "*the cursor does not refresh and simply writes the same 100 results to final_df.*" Probably because you're passing `cursor` as an HTTP header in the request itself, rather than as a query parameter in the endpoint URL - they are two fundamentally different things and are not interchangable.

Comment: Specifically, you need to add the "next" token as the `from` query parameter as shown in the documentation you pasted in your question.